# Make always invoks some dependency rules each time it runs

Tags: python, makefile

I have situation where I need to run some python scripts remotly and need to select and copy a few files to a remote folder. I am doing this in two stages. I copy files to a temp folder and then make an archive ready to send.

I created makefile to automate the first stage but it seems to work a little strange. The makefile looks as follows:

```
# Makefile and user paths
mkfile_path = $(dir $(realpath $(firstword $(MAKEFILE_LIST))))
user_path = $(shell echo $$HOME)

# Dependencies
ENTDIR = entropy
BINDIR = binary-files
MODDIR = modules
NORTH = $(BINDIR)/north
SOUTH = $(BINDIR)/south
WEST = $(BINDIR)/west
DISK = $(MODDIR)/disk
GEN = $(MODDIR)/general
PROB = $(MODDIR)/probability
NLTK = nltk_data
METAVAR = obj-meta-vars

# Target
TARGET=scripts-to-run-remotely.tar.gz

# Rules
all : $(TARGET)
    @echo "Complete"

$(TARGET) : $(NORTH)/north.obj \
        $(SOUTH)/south.obj \
        $(WEST)/west.obj \
        $(ENTDIR)/mifunction.py \
        $(ENTDIR)/miopt.py \
        $(ENTDIR)/miprint.py \
        $(ENTDIR)/run-logs.py \
        $(DISK)/%.py \
        $(GEN)/%.py \
        $(PROB)/%.py \
        $(METAVAR)/%.obj \
        $(NLTK)
    tar -czf $(TARGET) $(ENTDIR)/* $(BINDIR)/* $(MODDIR)/* $(NLTK)/* $(METAVAR)/*

# Files
$(NORTH)/north.obj: $(NORTH)
    cp /home/user/Documents/python/$(NORTH)/north.obj ./$(NORTH)

$(SOUTH)/south.obj: $(SOUTH)
    cp /home/user/Documents/python/$(SOUTH)/south.obj ./$(SOUTH)

$(WEST)/west.obj: $(WEST)
    cp /home/user/Documents/python/$(WEST)/west.obj ./$(WEST)

$(DISK)/%.py: $(DISK)
    cp /home/user/Documents/python/$(DISK)/*.py ./$(DISK)

$(GEN)/%.py: $(GEN)
    cp /home/user/Documents/python/$(GEN)/*.py ./$(GEN)

$(PROB)/%.py: $(PROB)
    cp /home/user/Documents/python/$(PROB)/*.py ./$(PROB)

$(ENTDIR)/mifunction.py: $(ENTDIR)
    cp /home/user/Documents/python/$(ENTDIR)/mifunction.py ./$(ENTDIR)

$(ENTDIR)/optmi.py: $(ENTDIR)
    cp /home/user/Documents/python/$(ENTDIR)/miopt.py ./$(ENTDIR)

$(ENTDIR)/printmi.py: $(ENTDIR)
    cp /home/user/Documents/python/$(ENTDIR)/miprint.py ./$(ENTDIR)

$(ENTDIR)/run-logs.py: $(ENTDIR)
    cp /home/user/Documents/python/$(ENTDIR)/run-logs.py ./$(ENTDIR)

$(METAVAR)/%.obj: $(METAVAR)
    cp /home/user/Dropbox/data/outputs/$(METAVAR)/*.obj ./$(METAVAR)

# Folders
$(NORTH):
    mkdir -p $@

$(SOUTH):
    mkdir -p $@

$(WEST):
    mkdir -p $@

$(ENTDIR):
    mkdir -p $@

$(DISK):
    mkdir -p $@

$(GEN):
    mkdir -p $@

$(PROB):
    mkdir -p $@

$(METAVAR):
    mkdir -p $@

$(NLTK):
    mkdir -p $@
    @python3 -m nltk.downloader wordnet wordnet_ic averaged_perceptron_tagger -d $(mkfile_path)/$(NLTK)

clean:
    @rm -rf ./$(TARGET) ./$(ENTDIR) ./$(BINDIR) ./$(MODDIR) ./$(METAVAR) ./$(NLTK)
    @echo "All files and folders removed"

# Always run those:
.PHONY: all
```

The first things I'd like to ask is how to avoid redundancy; if possible, how to avoid repeating parts of a code.

The second thing is when I run `make` for the first time, it runs through all rules where fodlers need to be created and then through all rules where files need to be copied. When I run `make` again, it invokes rules related to copying files:

```
cp /home/user/Documents/python/entropy/mifunction.py ./entropy
cp /home/user/Documents/python/entropy/miopt.py ./entropy
cp /home/user/Documents/python/entropy/miprint.py ./entropy
cp /home/user/Documents/python/entropy/run-logs.py ./entropy
cp /home/user/Documents/python/modules/disk/*.py ./modules/disk
cp /home/user/Documents/python/modules/general/*.py ./modules/general
cp /home/user/Documents/python/modules/probability/*.py ./modules/probability
cp /home/user/Dropbox/data/outputs/obj-meta-vars/*.obj ./obj-meta-vars
tar -czf enropy/* binary-files/* modules/* nltk_data/* obj-meta-vars/*
Complete
```

I am guessing there must be something wrong with the dependency related to checking existing folders.

Thanks.

Comment: Is the variable `$(ENSUS)` defined in the line `(ENSUS)/south.obj: $(SOUTH)`? Why do you make the `all` target a `.PHONY` one? It would be much easier if to help if you make up a small example with only parts of your makefile...

Comment: Yes `ENSUS` should be `SOUTH`. `all` is `.PHONY` because I wanted `all` target to be always executed. As to length of the example, I see and will make a next example shorter. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your copying rules have this form:

```
$(ENTDIR)/mifunction.py: $(ENTDIR)
    cp /home/user/Documents/python/$(ENTDIR)/mifunction.py ./$(ENTDIR)
```

Notice that the *destination directory* is a prerequisite. Make will consider the target out of date if the directory has a later timestamp than the target, and the OS updates the timestamp of the directory *when a file is added to it* (or removed). Since this makefile copies other files to that directory, this target will appear to be out of date the next time you run Make.

There is more than one way to solve this. The simplest is to change the prerequisite to an [order-only prerequisite](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Prerequisite-Types) by adding a pipe ('|'):

```
$(ENTDIR)/mifunction.py: | $(ENTDIR)
    cp /home/user/Documents/python/$(ENTDIR)/mifunction.py ./$(ENTDIR)
```

Once you confirm that this works, you can work on other improvements. You might consider using the original files as prerequisites:

```
$(ENTDIR)/mifunction.py: /home/user/Documents/python/$(ENTDIR)/mifunction.py | $(ENTDIR)
    cp /home/user/Documents/python/$(ENTDIR)/mifunction.py ./$(ENTDIR)
```

This looks ungainly until you introduce [automatic variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Automatic-Variables):

```
$(ENTDIR)/mifunction.py: /home/user/Documents/python/$(ENTDIR)/mifunction.py | $(ENTDIR)
    cp $< $@
```

Whether or not you do that, you can introduce another variable:

```
PYTHON_DIR := /home/user/Documents/python
```

which will remove a lot of redundancy.

Further improvements are possible, but that's probably enough for now.

Answer (score 1):

Trying to answer to the avoid-repition part of the questions: First, use automatic variables to refer to targets or prerequisites inside rules, e.g.

```
$(WEST)/west.obj: $(WEST)
    cp /home/user/Documents/python/$@ $<
```

The rule should then look identical at quite a few places, which enables the next change - define identical rules as a variable:

```
COPY = cp /home/user/Documents/python/$@ $<

$(WEST)/west.obj: $(WEST)
    $(COPY)
```

Next, use variables for your paths, e.g.

```
PYTHON_SOURCE_PATH = /home/user/Documents/python/
```

and use this variable in all your rules that need it (or the COPY variable as shown before). You should be able to change this path by only editing this particular line where the variable is set up. Next, collect your directories that are possibly created in a variable, too. Then, a lot of rules can be replaced by a single one:

```
DIRECTORIES = $(NORTH) $(SOUTH) # ... the others

$(DIRECTORIES):
    mkdir -p $@
```